# Signing SOAP messages using WSS4J

Tags: java, soap, websphere, wss4j

We need to sign a SOAP message with a certificate in Websphere 7.  Currently we are looking at using WSS4J from Apache and are approaching this in the java code itself.

Does anyone have any experience signing SOAP messages in Websphere or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Francis,

Websphere 7 has native support for several WS-Security scenarios. Did you already check the documentation?

- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/twbs_wsspsenc.html
- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.pmc.express.doc/tasks/tjw_wss_conf_new.html

thanks,
dims

Comment: Thanks for that Dims.  It seems clear that doing this through Java directly is not a good idea.  Using WS looks far more promising.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using the [WSSSignPart API](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/twbs_confsignaturepartgen.html)?